# Magento VAT not being included in price on product page (and, yes, shipping origin IS set correctly)

Tags: magento

I have a puzzling problem.  I have set up my catalog to include VAT in the prices but for some reason (although VAT is being calculated correctly) it is NOT being displayed correctly including VAT on the product pages.  The products' prices include VAT, I have configured Magento so that prices include VAT, etc. but nonetheless VAT is actually being backed out of the prices on the product page.

I HAVE SET the shipping origin correctly and VAT is being calculated correctly.  Obviously, I'm missing something.

HELP!

Summary:

Prices shown correctly in backend (includes VAT)
Prices shown incorrectly in frontend (does not include VAT)
Tax calculation based on shipping address
Shipping origin set properly
Catalog prices including tax
Shipping prices including tax
VAT calculated correctly

Answer (score 1):

have you checked below setting :-
System configuration >> tax >> Price Display Setting >> Display Product Prices In Catalog